# Replace number in pgf-pie

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I am using pgf-pie to create pie charts.
Usually, the number is written into the slices. I would like to replace the number by another string and the same time keep the description pinned.

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[ 
        /tikz/every pin/.style={align=left},
        sum=auto,
        radius=2,
        text=pin,
        rotate=120 ,
        % before number=\phantom,
        %  after number=,
        color={red!70,blue!70}
        ]{
        14.850/$\textbf{Not supported}$\\ (59.7\%),
        10.009/$\textbf{Supported}$\\ (40.3\%)
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So Instead 14.850 I want 14850 and instead 10.009 I want 10009.

Is that possible?

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1):

Update: `pgf-pie` has renamed some internals. The following MWE works for the version on Github dated December 26th 2020 (https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie). The original code below still works for the version currently on CTAN (May 2020).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\pgfpie@numbertext}[1]
{
  \pgfpie@ifhidenumber{}{%
  \pgfpie@beforenumber\StrSubstitute{#1}{.}{}\pgfpie@afternumber%
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[ 
        /tikz/every pin/.style={align=left},
        sum=auto,
        radius=2,
        text=pin,
        rotate=120 ,
        color={red!70,blue!70}
        ]{
        14.850/\textbf{Not supported}\\(59.7\%),
        10.009/\textbf{Supported}\\ (40.3\%)
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

For the question as asked after the edit (print the original label without the dot) a quick workaround can be used by redefining `\pgfpie@numbertext`, which is the internal macro in `pgf-pie` that prints the numbers. With the `xstring` package you can substitute the dot for the empty string. The code below is for an older version of `pgf-pie` (May 2020).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\pgfpie@numbertext}[1]
{
  \ifhidenumber
  \else
  \pgfpie@beforenumber\StrSubstitute{#1}{.}{}\pgfpie@afternumber
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[ 
        /tikz/every pin/.style={align=left},
        sum=auto,
        radius=2,
        text=pin,
        rotate=120 ,
        color={red!70,blue!70}
        ]{
        14.850/\textbf{Not supported}\\(59.7\%),
        10.009/\textbf{Supported}\\ (40.3\%)
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Original answer:

To replace the number with the label you can use a combination of `hide number` and `text=inside`. Note that because the text is relatively long it does not fit inside the slices in the default (centered) position of the number. You can push the text a bit down for the left slice by introducing some vertical space with `\vspace`. This needs to be negative, and for some reason it should be specified in the second line and not the first.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[ 
        /tikz/every pin/.style={align=left},
        sum=auto,
        radius=2,
        hide number,
        text=inside,
        rotate=120 ,
        % before number=\phantom,
        %  after number=,
        color={red!70,blue!70}
        ]{
        14.850/\textbf{Not supported}\\\vspace{-10mm}(59.7\%),
        10.009/\textbf{Supported}\\ (40.3\%)
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I would like leave the description pinned outside and replace the number 14.850 by 14850. 
I can't write large numbers because then I get "dimension too large"

Comment: @Amit I see, that was not clear to me from your question. I'll have to think about an approach for that problem.

Comment: Thanks, I edit the question.

Comment: @Amit I added a workaround for the clarified question.

Comment: thanks for help. It works fine. I found also another workaround but your solution is much more elegant.